# Etymology of »Gefährten«

Tags: etymology

I came across the film "Gefährten" (War Horse) and I thought the title had something to do with *gefährlich* with it being a war film and all.  But I see that it means companion.

Does anyone know the etymology of »*Gefährten*«?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those words have distinct etymological roots and therefore different meanings:

### die Gefahr

(danger, risk, hazard)

The Middle High German noun

> gevāre

was built by adding the prefix »ge« to the noun »vāre«. This prefix just makes a stronger expression to the noun, without changing its core-meaning. »vāre« itself derives fron the Old High German

> fāra

and had the meaning

> ambush, temptation, to be after someone, revolt, rebellion, deceitfulness, ...

Also the englisch word »fear« dereives from this word.

---

### der Gefährte, die Gefährtin

(fellow, companion, partner, associate)

In Middle High German this was

> geverte, gevert

Here we have the same emphasizing prefix »ge«, joined to »vert(e)« which is a grammatical form of the noun

> vart

and this again is the noun-version of the verb

> varn

this verb is in modern German

> fahren

and means today: to travel (in a vehicle). but centuries ago it just meant any kind of traveling, also walking on longer distances.

The Old High German version of this verb was

> faran

and it also meant »to travel«, but not only in a physical way, but also in a metaphoric way. This meaning is still alive in the modern English verb »to fare« (someone fares well/badly) that derives from OHG *faran*.

So a »Gefährte« is a person who travels together with another person. The persons traveling together are »Gefährten«. The common journey can be a real journey from point A to point B, but also a metaphoric journey, where the *Gefährten* experience the same fate.

[image: Die Gefährten]

Comment: The English words "fear" and "fare" do not derive from OHG. Rather the OE and OHG words both derive from proto-Germanic.

Answer (score 0):

[dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gef%C3%A4hrte) says:

> Gefährte m. ‘Begleiter’, ahd. giferto ‘Fahrtgenosse’ (9. Jh.), mhd. geverte, mnd. gevērde bezeichnet als Kompositum zu den unter Fahrt (s. d.) genannten Wortformen mit dem Präfix ge- ‘zusammen mit’ ursprünglich den, ‘der die Fahrt mit (einem) anderen gemeinsam macht’, den ‘Mitreisenden, Reisebegleiter’ (zur Bildung s. auch Bauer, Genosse, Geselle).

Comment: Just as a comment: "Gefahr"/ "gefährlich" have a different origin than "Gefährte". https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gefahr (--> Etymologie)

Comment: And why the downvote?